# Error autoloading namespace in another namespace

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I am getting the below error when trying to call `m_newEmployee` from `c_index.php`.

I tried:

```
$employee = new \App\model\newEmployee;
```

but this caused another weird error in `m_newEmployee`.

When I do that the function `getEmployees()` cant be used to create any objects.

c_index.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controller;

use app\model;

require_once "../task/vendor/autoload.php";
  /**
   *
   */
  class c_index
  {

      function loadEmployees()
      {
         $employee = new m_newEmployee;
         echo $employee->getEmployees();
      }


  }


 ?>
```

m_newEmployee.php

```
<?php

namespace app\model;
require_once "../task/vendor/autoload.php";
/**
 *
 */
class m_newEmployee
{
    function createTable()
    {
        $database = new m_database;
        $conn = $database->connect();

        // sql to create table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        employee VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        )";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
    }


  function createEmployee($employee)
  {

      $this->createTable();
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `employees`( `employee`) VALUES ('$employee')";
       if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

           $result = true;
           return $result;
       } else {
           echo "Error inserting  " . $conn->error;
       }
  }


  function getEmployees()
  {
      $database = new m_database;
      $conn = $database->connect();

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employees`";
      if ($result = $conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

            //Initialize array variable
            $dbdata = array();

          //Fetch into associative array
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
            $dbdata[]=$row;
            }

          //Print array in JSON format
           return json_encode($dbdata);
      }

      else {
          echo "Error inserting  " . $conn->error;
      }
    }
  }
```

composer.json

```
{
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
      "":"app",
       "App\\":"app"
    }
}

}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'm_newEmployee' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\app\controller\c_index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\task\index.php(14): app\controller\c_index->loadEmployees() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\app\controller\c_index.php on line 16

Comment: `m_newEmployee.php` is in the `model` folder? Looks like you're mixing case on your namespace, most places it's `app`, but in your autoloader it's `App`, I think that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Importing namespace (`use app\model;`) does not mean that you can use models from this namespace directly. You need to either specify namespace (using short name from import):

```
namespace app\controller;
use app\model;
// ...
$employee = new model\m_newEmployee();
```

Or import model directly:

```
namespace app\controller;
use app\model\m_newEmployee;
// ...
$employee = new m_newEmployee();
```

Comment: Then you have also autoloading problem. Make sure that namespaces and class names matches file paths (including case) and try remove `"":"app",` from you `composer.json`.